# In Objective-C, what is the equivalent of Java's "instanceof" keyword?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to check whether an object (e.g. `someObject`) is assignable (cast-able) to a variable of another type (e.g. `SpecifiedType`). In Java, I can write:

```java
someObject instanceof SpecifiedType
```

A related question is finding whether the runtime type of an object is equal to a another type. In Java, I can write:

```java
someObject.getClass().equals(SpecifiedType.class)
```

How can this be done in Objective-C?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8294076/165674

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Try `[myObject class]` for returning the class of an object.

You can make exact comparisons with:

```
if ([myObject class] == [MyClass class])
```

but not by using directly `MyClass` identifier.

Similarily, you can find if the object is of a subclass of your class with:

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[AnObject class]])
```

as suggested by Jon Skeet and zoul.

Comment: How would I check for equality with an object of type "AnObject" for example?

Comment: "if ([myObject class] == [AnObject class])" or, as suggested by Jon Skeet and zoul: "if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[AnObject class]])"

Comment: exact comparison can also be done with `if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[MyClass class]])`

Answer (score 37):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_(computer_science)#Objective-C):

> In Objective-C, for example, both the
>   generic `Object` and `NSObject` (in
>   Cocoa/OpenStep) provide the method
>   `isMemberOfClass:` which returns `true` if
>   the argument to the method is an
>   instance of the specified class. The
>   method `isKindOfClass:` analogously
>   returns true if the argument inherits
>   from the specified class.

`isKindOfClass:` would be closest to `instanceof`, by the sounds of it.

Answer (score 9):

See the [isKindOfClass:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) method in the [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. (The usual word of warning for such question is that checking the object class is often a sign of doing something wrong.)

Comment: Just copying from the "answer" below: "@Zoul - why is using class type checking considered bad? Is this not good defensive programming or are you arguing it should be unnecessary?"

Comment: Aha, thanks. One problem is that objects do not have to be of the class you are expecting. During testing it’s quite common to pass a class stub that honours the interface, but has a different class. Or when you observe value changes using KVO there’s certain magic done with the classes. Both cases are quite legit and both are easily broken if your code does explicit class checks. Switching behaviour on class is poor OO design, tightly coupled and hard to extend. I am not saying there is no legit use case for class checks, but you should think twice before doing it.

Comment: @zoul In that specific case this would be just plain inexperience, one would more likely use `+ (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol`.