# In Objective-C, how do I test the object type?

Tags: objective-c

I need to test whether the object is of type `NSString` or `UIImageView`. How can I accomplish this? Is there some type of "isoftype" method?

Comment: Yes there is: `[object isKindOfClass:[ClassName class]]`

Comment: See: [In Objective-C what is the equivelant of the java “instanceof” keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536396/in-objective-c-what-is-the-equivelant-of-the-java-instanceof-keyword)

Answer (score 913, accepted):

If your object is `myObject`, and you want to test to see if it is an `NSString`, the code would be:

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

Likewise, if you wanted to test `myObject` for a `UIImageView`:

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]
```

Comment: Note that there is also a isMemberOfClass: method that will check for class "exactness." Be careful with it though, as many Apple objects are actually Core Foundation types in disguise. (Eg. an NSString is more often an NSCFString, and isMemberOfClass: will return false for this comparison.)

Comment: Note this method is very slow!

Comment: Is that right knowing that NSString is a class cluster? (like NSNumber)

Comment: but this answer isnt in the form of a test, like with kiwi or something

Answer (score 54):

You would probably use

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

This is a method of `NSObject`.

For more info check the `NSObject` documentation.

This is how you use this.

```
BOOL test = [self isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]];
```

You might also try doing somthing like this

```
for(id element in myArray)
{
    NSLog(@"=======================================");
    NSLog(@"Is of type: %@", [element className]);
    NSLog(@"Is of type NSString?: %@", ([[element className] isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
    NSLog(@"Is a kind of NSString: %@", ([[element classForCoder] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");    
}
```

Comment: -1: Don't use `className`, it may or may not work on OS X, but it's not in iOS and it's not meant to be used for this. Also, those `NSLog`s don't do what I think you meant them to--they are checking the class name (always a string) and the coder class, strangely, instead of the class of the actual element.

Comment: For a quick check this: `NSLog(@"Is of type: %@", [element class]);`  will work in iOS 7

Comment: @PortlandRunner : This is exactly what I was looking for.  IDK if there is a ticket that addresses that exact thing better, but if not, you should create one.  If you do, I let me know and I will upvote the answer there, as this snippet was clutch for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

When you want to differ between a superClass and the inheritedClass you can use:

```
if([myTestClass class] == [myInheritedClass class]){
   NSLog(@"I'm the inheritedClass);
} 
if([myTestClass class] == [mySuperClass class]){
   NSLog(@"I'm the superClass);
}
```

Using `- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass` in this case would result in TRUE both times because the inheritedClass is also a kind of the superClass.

Comment: `isMemberOfClass:` will return `NO` when dealing with subclasses.

Answer (score 14):

Running a simple test, I thought I'd document what works and what doesn't.  Often I see people checking to see if the object's class is a member of the other class or is equal to the other class.

For the line below, we have some poorly formed data that can be an `NSArray`, an `NSDictionary` or `(null)`.

```
NSArray *hits = [[[myXML objectForKey: @"Answer"] objectForKey: @"hits"] objectForKey: @"Hit"];
```

These are the tests that were performed:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);

if ([hits isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}

if ([hits isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [hits class]);
}
```

`isKindOfClass` worked rather well while `isMemberOfClass` didn't.

Comment: I see you shared code for tests. But where are the printed result?

Comment: The idea is for you to copy my code and see the results for what you need.

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of the following code incase you want to check the types of primitive data types.

```
// Returns 0 if the object type is equal to double
strcmp([myNumber objCType], @encode(double))
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple, [yourobject  class] it will return the class name of yourobject.

Comment: Actually it will return a `Class` object. However, the `description` of this object will be the class name as a string, so you can therefore still log it to the console.