# How to calculate tableView row height and pass value to heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, height, tableview, custom-cell

I've a **tableView** with custom cells.
Each cell has different interface, elements. All they have different sizes.
Each cell has different type of elements and their count.
All these elements are created dynamically, so I'm creating them, making their frames and adding as **subviews**.

So the problem that **heightForRowAtIndexPath** executes before **cellForRowAtIndexPath** where I'm creating the row and constructing its interface and I don't know how to pass calculated height to **heightForRowAtIndexPath**

How can I count row height **before** and **pass its value to heightForRowIndexPath** for correct drawing of my tableView?

Comment: so you know what is the view frame for each cell but dont know what is the height of the cell?

Comment: I dont know how to pass calculated height into heightForRowAtIndexPath which only can change row height, as I understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cell view is really very complex and every component's height are depending on data source. You can try to create the view in `heightForRowIndexPath` method and then cache the created view to a dictionary in your view controller and use it directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In this way you only need to create the view once when user scrolling the table. If the datasource is not changing very frequently, you can reuse the cached view in `heightForRowIndexPath` as well.

And if the tableview has a lot of rows, you should return an approximate value for height in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` to speed up the loading process of the view controller. Otherwise during loading tableview, it will try to calculate all row's height which may requires a lot of time.

But I really don't think your cell would be so complex. If only some UITextLabels that depends on datasource for the height, you can simply only calculate the height for the label, then add it to other components' height which is fixed.

Comment: About its complex - it is. Its social network and when I'll do the wall with users post - their all can contain a text, pictures (up to 10), audio, video, documents and other attached to them. Also it can be a re-post, so all content will be shifted a bit and upper it will be the post-creator name. So there is no way to calculated row height in its uitableviewcell.swift-file and then pass it to the original heightForRowAtIndexPath, is it?

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich no really, you can check the design carefully and extract some patterns out. For example, for images, audio, video or documents, the height for each single item usually would be fixed, you can get the total height by numberOfTheItem*eachItemHeight.

Comment: Thats it. So the question is about setting calculated height to rowHeight correctly.

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich You can try my solution first, since you have the code to create view already, it should be very fast. If it works fine, your problem solved. But if you have performance issues, then we need to find other solution.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll try. Thanks to you

Comment: but the bad thing about such way to do is that I can not separate code of creating different rows, all of those must be in heightForRowAtIndexPath and it will be hard to read and understand it later

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich How do you separate code in cellForRowAtIndexPath? you can do it same way in heightForRowAtIndexPath, because the two methods have the same parameter.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm creating a cell depended to indexPath.row and calling function in them which construct their interface. All of cells has different type - custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich I think your problem is the cell type. You can still use it in heightForRowAtIndexPath! For the cache dictionary, you use UITableViewCell as the type and in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you just directly return the cache view, no need to cast it to custom view.

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich If you still want to cast it to corresponding class, you can use the isKindOfClass method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368124/iphone-how-to-check-the-type-of-an-object

Answer (score 2):

You really should consider subclassing UITableViewCell and adding your custom logic inside your subclass.

Starting from there, you'll have such options:

1. Create static method in your cell that will receive all data necessary to draw your cell (e.g heithtForCellWithFirstString:secondString:accessoryImage etc) and calculate height using string size computation methods. Use this method inside heightForRowAtIndexPath.
2. Use autolayout for laying out subviews of your cell and then set table view's row height property to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. This way you won't need heightForRow delegate method at all. There are plenty of tutorials on this, for example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: Thanks. But if I calculate height inside heightForRowAtIndexPath and in the cell separatly - in will be twice executed the same operation. About autolayout - I thought about that, but elements have different positions all the time and also it can be that there is no one element so it will be nothing to connect to row top or bottom. That's why I need any advice about implementing some logic decision in my case

Comment: Calculating height before cellForRow is another operation - as it doesn't involve view creation. It's just string.sizeWithAttributes and your custom margins arithmetics

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.
2. All elements created by you put inside `UIView`, which is put in a cell.
3. Create three `NSLayoutConstraint`, one from `UIView.top` to top of the cell, the second from `UIView.bottom` to the bottom of the cell and the third - the height of the `UIView`.
4. In the `viewDidLoad` method of `tableViewController` set row height as the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

5. In a subclass of UITableViewCell create a method that will calculate the height of the cell and change NSLayoutConstraint, which sets the height of the cell. For example:

:

```
func adjustHeightOfInnerView() {
   let height = 100
   self.myInnerCellViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
   self.contentView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

6. In the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call the `adjustHeightOfTableview`:

:

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCellSubclass
   cell.adjustHeightOfTableview()
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Big thanks to you. I'll try it in the evening at home

Comment: can you please help me with third step?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to do it correctly. I tried something like this let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: btn, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
 but nothing changed

Comment: You called `contentView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` after creating constraints?

Comment: Create `UIView` and constraints in Interface Builder.
Create a IBOutlet on heightConstraint in CustomTableViewCell and change its value programmatically.

Comment: I'm working without storyboards. All interface builds programmatically

Comment: Ok! I'm ready to send you a working example. How to contact you?