# search element in NSDictionary nested in another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Background:

a Object:

```
MyObject : NSObject
@property NSInteger type;
```

a NSDictionary:

```
@{
@"1":@{@"1":MyObject}
@"2":@{@"1":MyObject}
}
```

Now,got a MyObject and it's type=1;
how to make sure whether this MyObject contained in the NSDictionary?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886077/check-whether-an-object-is-an-nsarray-or-nsdictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking into consideration, that your dictionary only has one key/pair and there are no similar key names present

```
  NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"a":@{@"c":@"MyObject"}                                        ,@"b":@{@"d":@"MyObject"} } ;

NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 // enumerate and add all values to our value array
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Your value : %@", [obj description]);

    [valuesArray addObject:[[obj allValues] firstObject]];
}];

// check whether this value is present
if ([valuesArray containsObject:@"MyObject"]) {
    NSLog(@"My Object found",);
}
```

Comment: @{
    @"a":@{@"c":MyObject}
    @"b":@{@"d":MyObject}
    }

Comment: you want to check whether myObject is present?