# NSArray sorting thanks to another NSArray

Tags: sorting, nsarray

I have a NSArray containing some objects.

`NSArray *firstArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj, plop, color, shape, nil];`

Now I have another NSArray containing only objects from the first NSArray, but not in the same order.

`NSArray *secondArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: shape, color, plop, nil];`

I would like to sort the secondArray in the same order that in the firstArray.

I want secondArray to be :

- plop
- color
- shape

Answer (score 1):

NSArray is already ordered so you can use it at your advantage: why just don't you search what objects are inside the firstArray but not inside the secondArray then remove then from the first array ?

```
NSMutableArray *arrayObjectsInFirstArrayNotInSecondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
[arrayObjectsInFirstArrayNotInSecondArray removeObjectsInArray:secondArray];

NSMutableArray *solution = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
[solution removeObjectsInArray:arrayObjectsInFirstArrayNotInSecondArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is the kind of thing for which I'd automatically point people to [Apple's NSSortDescriptor Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but it sounds like what you are doing is very application & object specific.

If your shape, color and plop objects are true Cocoa objects (i.e. [they respond to  `isKindOfClass` selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144629/in-objective-c-how-do-i-test-the-object-type)), you can go through each piece of your `secondArray` and create a new mutable array (let's call it `thirdArray` for argument's sake) and use enumeration on the elements of `secondArray` to insert each object into `thirdArray` in the format that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;) Actually those objects come from the same Cocoa Class. I'll see that, thanks you ;)

Comment: But is there a way to compare with [firstArray indexOfObject:(id)] ?

Comment: Sure! You now know how to determine the type of whatever object you've stored in both `secondArray` AND `firstArray`.  Or are you talking about the contents of each object that you've stored in the arrays (i.e. `NSString` comparing to another `NSString` or `NSNumber` or?)??

Comment: To sum up, I would like to sort the objects in 'secondArray' using their index in 'firstArray'. I don't really need to check their type ;) Do you understand ? ? ^^' (I'm a french 17 years old guy, it's hard to make myself understand sometimes, sorry ^^')

Comment: Can't answer now but i did :    [secondArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                              {
                                  if ([firstArray indexOfObject:obj1] >  [firstArray indexOfObject:obj2])
                                      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                                  
                                  else
                                      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    
                                  
                              }]

It works ;)