# With an NSDictionary, can you determine data type of the value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

For iOS, given some `NSDictionary` key/value pairs where strings values were added as `NSString` and `int`/`float` values were added as `NSNumber`, is there a way to test the data type of a value to see whether it is `NSString` or `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

NSObject offers:

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

if obj is the value you get out of the NSDictionary then checkout:

```
[obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
[obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]
```

If you check for these and you don't expect anything but NSString or NSNumber in the dictionary, then I would add an NSAssert in the else block.

There's more comments here on nuances of NSString and NSCFString:

[In Objective-C, how do I test the object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144629/in-objective-c-how-do-i-test-the-object-type)

Answer (score 8):

Dictionary return an id you can check its class type as follows

```
if ([[dictionary valueForKey:@"key"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"it is a string");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"it is number");
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the object is nil or [NSNull null].