# UITableView in UICollectionView not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touch, uicollectionview

I have `UITableViews` nested in custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s, but the table views are not responding to touch input - either scrolling or firing `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate` protocol.

Both the `CollectionView` and `TableView` Cells are populating with the correct data, so I believe it is something to do with the `CollectionViewCell`'s intercepting the touch events.

Is there a way to make the embedded `TableView` take precedence?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Sorry it says like "Avoid comments like "thanks"" so I didn't reply.

Unfortunately that wasn't what I was looking for but it's handy to know, and I'll probably need it later.

I did manage to fix my problem, but I'm not overly sure how - or I would have posted it. I just remade the custom cell in the Interface Builder  and it started working. Should have done that earlier as I was stuck on it for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using these methods: [canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:) and [canPreventGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/canPreventGestureRecognizer:). Get the gesture recognizers of the `UITableView` and the `UICollectionView` by using their [gestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/gestureRecognizers) method (they will have more than one obviously, so you gotta pick the one you're interested in [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144664/766570) a something like

```
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:UITapGestureRecognizer])
  // have fun here
```

that should do it!