# Objective-C Type Testing

Tags: objective-c, typeof

How would I test the type of a primitive data type in Objective-C?

```
- (IBAction)coor1X: (id)sender {
if(typeof(<value of sender>) == double) {
         ...
}
}
```

The sender is a UITextField in the Interface Builder. I need the input to be a double.
Iv'e tried typeof() but it doesn't work the way I intended. I have also looked to find how to get the value of the text field, I'm having trouble finding that also.

Thanks!

Comment: What types are you checking for?

Comment: Your `sender` probably will never be a `double`... What are you trying to do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Objective-C, how do I test the object type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144629/in-objective-c-how-do-i-test-the-object-type)

Comment: double is not an obj-c object type. also there is no typeof() operator on objective-c. there is no run time type checking in C either. Obj-C provides an *-isKindOfClass:* method (among others).

Comment: The real question is: what are you building that needs you to do a type check? Most of the time they are unnecessary.

Comment: The input from a UILabel will never be a double. It is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you mean is that you are receiving a string from a UILabel (its `text`) and you are hoping that it is the string representation of a number. In the simplest cases, you can call `doubleValue` or a similar NSString method to determine whether this is true. It will return `0.0` if the string is not the string representation of a double. See the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/doubleValue

In more complicated situations, you can use NSScanner to help analyze the string (e.g. to learn whether it contains a number, even if it is not a number).

Comment: Or instead of NSScanner use an NSNumberFormatter or more easily use NSRegularExpression.

Comment: Does NSNumberFormatter change the type of Strings to NSNumbers?         @uchuugaka

Comment: No. It formats the string in a locale sensitive way to present test representing a number according to display rules.

Comment: @uchuugaka The thing is that I don't know the regex pattern for the string representation of a double. But NSScanner does!

Comment: Well, it's potentially more complex when we consider locale differences and that the string might be a valid number entered by the user. So NSScanner won't find that as easily as a regular expression. Regular expressions allow patterns that represent whole classes of Unicode characters. But an NSNumberFormatter is the most appropriate approach to simply limit the field input to a valid input. It also handles locale differences. Keep in mind at the very least that . And , are used differently in different locales. Not to mention other scripts entirely.

Comment: Also I misspoke about NSNumberFormatter earlier. It easily converts number to string and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

you can check it like this

for example

[myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]

Answer (score 1):

In your code `sender` is going to be a pointer to an Objective-C class. It's safe to assume that the class will be a subclass of `NSObject`, so you can use the `NSObject` method `-isKindOfClass:` like so:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:<some class name>])
{
    ...
}
```

A `double` is not an Objective-C object, so you can't test it with `-isKindOfClass:`. Likewise, you can't test an Objective-C object with `typeof()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this you know data type of any .. try this may be helpfull

```
NSLog(@"Variable type get %@",[variableObject class]);
```

Thanks & Cheers...