# XCode - trace datatype - typeof?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i´ve searched the xcode doku but didn´t found anything about logging the datatype of a variable. How can i trace the typeof ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate of: [In Objective-C, what is the equivalent of Java's "instanceof" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536396/in-objective-c-what-is-the-equivelant-of-the-java-instanceof-keyword)

Summary:

> Try `[myObject class]` for returning the class of an object.
>
> You can make exact comparisons with:
>
> ```
> if ([myObject class] == [MyClass class])
> ```
>
> but not by using directly `MyClass` identifier.
>
> Similarily, you can find if the object is of a subclass of your class with:
>
> ```
> if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[AnObject class]])
> ```
>
> as suggested by Jon Skeet and zoul.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  It helped a lot when I was trying to separate an array!!  Thanks.