# Get a reference to class object from uninitialized variable - not instantiated object

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, typeof, variable-types

Let's say I have an uninitialized variable:

```
UIViewController *vc;
```

From this variable, I want to reference `UIViewController`, such that I could call `alloc` or `new` on it to return an instantiated object.

Essentially, I want to do:

```
UIViewController *vc = [*typeof(vc) new];
```

... which does not compile because the compiler expects an expression rather than a type.

If `@encode` returned the actual type, I could do something like:

```
UIViewController *vc = [NSClassFromString(@(@encode(*typeof(vc)))) new];
```

...however, `@encode` returns '@', which just means "generic object".

I realize it's a little philosophical in nature, but I get tired of typing and would like to make a macro like `NEW(x)`.  I also realize a similar macro could be made if it involves the actual declaration, but I am not satisfied with that syntax/angle.

Comment: `#define NEW(class, varname) class * varname = [class new]` is unsatisfactory, you're saying?

Comment: Yeah.  I came up with something (see my answer), but it's not awesome.  I probably won't end up doing this.

Comment: Similar problem, but not identical because you still have access to the local declaration: [ObjC can you test an uninitialized pointer for static class type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7680310) It explains why this isn't generally possible, however.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace perfectly fine code with obfuscated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have... it doesn't seem ideal, since it makes a performance hit.  Still looking for better answers.

```
static Class classFromEncoding(const char *encoding) {
    char *className = strndup(encoding + 1, strchr(encoding, '=') - encoding - 1);
    Class retval = NSClassFromString(@(className));
    free(className);
    return retval;
}

#define NEW(variable) [classFromEncoding(@encode(typeof(*variable))) new]
```

Here's a macro-only version:

```
#define CLASS_FROM_VARIABLE(variable) \
^(const char *encoding) {             \
char *className = strndup(encoding + 1, strchr(encoding, '=') - encoding - 1); \
Class retval = NSClassFromString(@(className));      \
free(className);                         \
return retval;                              \
}(@encode(typeof(*variable)))

#define NEW(variable) [CLASS_FROM_VARIABLE(variable) new]
#define ALLOC(variable) [CLASS_FROM_VARIABLE(variable) alloc]
```

Variations can be made using objc_getClass() or NSString initWithBytes, perhaps with performance gains.  Still, it's not a no-op, which is what I'd prefer.

Comment: I would suggest that everybody who reads your code using this macro is going to put a hex on your gerbil.

Comment: I'd definitely limit my usage. :)  I love Objective-C, but initializers are the most annoying part of my day (which is why I've moved to the +new camp instead of alloc]init]).

Answer (score -1):

It's `[obj class]` or `[obj className]` depending on your needs.

Comment: The object hasn't been initialized; there's nothing to respond to these messages.

Comment: True, my bad. NSClassFromString() seems to be the best way than.